# How do I not let these 2 elements overlap - Anchored Button and ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a `Button` thats anchored to the bottom, and `ScrollView` that takes up the entire screen.  How do I not let these 2 elements overlap?  They're contained in a vertically oriented `RelativeLayout`. The `ScrollView` has `EditText`'s and the problem is when the last `EditText` gets the focus, it's being overlapped by the anchored `Button` initially.

Comment: Post your XML, and possibly some screenshots of what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the button above the Scrollview and added: `android:layout_above="@+id/MyButton"`  Where MyButton is the anchored button on the bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">
  <Button... 
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   />

  <ScrollView 
       android:layout_above="@+id/MyButton"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >...</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```